# Не работает скрипт js для таблицы, которая выводится средством php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Код js, который должен сортировать данные на клиентской части

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    const getSort = ({ target }) => {
        const order = (target.dataset.order = -(target.dataset.order || -1));
        const index = [...target.parentNode.cells].indexOf(target);
        const collator = new Intl.Collator(['en', 'ru'], { numeric: true });
        const comparator = (index, order) => (a, b) => order * collator.compare(
            a.children[index].innerHTML,
            b.children[index].innerHTML
        );
        
        for(const tBody of target.closest('table').tBodies)
            tBody.append(...[...tBody.rows].sort(comparator(index, order)));

        for(const cell of target.parentNode.cells)
            cell.classList.toggle('sorted', cell === target);
    };
    
    document.querySelectorAll('.table_sort thead').forEach(tableTH => tableTH.addEventListener('click', () => getSort(event)));
    
});
```

Код index.php (таблицу переписал в html чтобы не мозолить глаз ненужной информацией) c этой таблицей работает

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table_sort">
    <thead><tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>city</th>
                <th>car</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>"
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                Григорий
            </td>
            <td>
                Москва
            </td>
            <td>
                Porsche 911
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                Александр
            </td>
            <td>
                Пермь
            </td>
            <td>
                Subaru Impreza
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Как только вывожу таблицу средствами php, работать отказывается

```
<?php
    
    $dataCars = file_get_contents("data_cars.json");
    $decodeCars = json_decode($dataCars, true); //декодированный массив таблицы
    $arrayCountCars = count($decodeCars); //кол-во участников
    $parentKeyCars = array_keys(json_decode($dataCars, true)); //ключ родительского класса


    $dataAttempts = file_get_contents("data_attempts.json");
    $decodeAttempts = json_decode($dataAttempts, true); //декодированный массив таблицы
    $arrayCountAttempts = count($decodeAttempts); //кол-во заездов
    $parentKeyAttempts = array_keys(json_decode($dataAttempts, true)); //ключ родительского класса
    $arraySort = array();
    $bigData = array('id'=>"", 'name'=>"", 'resultData'=>"", 'sumResultData'=>"");
    $bigDataName = array($bigData["name"]);
    $bigDataResult = array($bigData["resultData"]);
    $bigDataSum = array($bigData["sumResultData"]);
    $bigDataId = array($bigData["id"]);

    $i = 0; //кол-во заездов
    $countAttempts = 0;
    echo "<h2>Реультаты</h2>";
    for ($j=0; $j < $arrayCountAttempts; $j++) {
        $childArrayAttempts = $decodeAttempts[$parentKeyAttempts[$j]];
        if ($childArrayAttempts["id"] == $parentKeyAttempts[$i+1]) {
            $countAttempts += 1;
            }
    }

    echo "<table class=\"table_sort\">";
    echo "<thead><tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Участник</th>";
        for ($i=0; $i < $countAttempts; $i++) { 
            echo "<th>Заезд №";
            echo $i + 1;
            echo "</th>";
        }
        echo "<th>Сумма очков</th>";
    echo "</tr></thead>";
    for ($i=0; $i < $arrayCountCars; $i++) { 
        $sumResult = 0;
        $childArrayCars = $decodeCars[$parentKeyCars[$i]];
        $bigDataId[] = $childArrayCars["id"];
        $bigDataName[] = $childArrayCars["name"];
        for ($j=0; $j < $arrayCountAttempts; $j++) {
            $childArrayAttempts = $decodeAttempts[$parentKeyAttempts[$j]];
            if ($childArrayAttempts["id"] == $parentKeyAttempts[$i+1]) {
                $sumResult += $childArrayAttempts["result"]; //сумма очков
                $bigDataResult[] = $childArrayAttempts["result"];
            }
        }
        $bigDataSum[] = $sumResult;

    } 
    $t = 1;
    for ($n=1; $n < $arrayCountCars + 1 ; $n++) { 
        $j = 0;
        echo "<tbody><tr>";
            echo "<td>$bigDataId[$n]</td>";
            echo "<td>$bigDataName[$n]</td>";
            while ($j < $countAttempts) {
                echo "<td>$bigDataResult[$t]</td>";
                $j++;
                $t++;
            }
            echo "<td>$bigDataSum[$n]</td>";
        echo "</tr></tbody>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Код css

```
<style>.table_sort table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
    color: #ffebcd;
    background: #008b8b;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #846868;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

.table_sort th {
    color: #ffebcd;
    background: #008b8b;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table_sort td,
.table_sort th {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #846868;
}

.table_sort tbody:nth-child(even) {
    background: #e3e3e3;
}

th.sorted[data-order=\"1\"],
th.sorted[data-order=\"-1\"] {
    position: relative;
}

th.sorted[data-order=\"1\"]::after,
th.sorted[data-order=\"-1\"]::after {
    right: 8px;
    position: absolute;
}

th.sorted[data-order=\"-1\"]::after {
    content: \"▼\"
}

th.sorted[data-order=\"1\"]::after {
    content: \"▲\"
}</style>
```

Comment: а в пхп вы подготовить данные нормально не в состоянии, чтобы сразу вывести как  надо и не делать вот это на js при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Каким образом? Сортировка таблицы должна проходить на клиентской части

Comment: а. пропустил, что у вас там в конце привязывается на клики в хэдер таблицы. Тогда вы из вопроса выкиньте весь ваш пхп, коли он нормальную верстку делает, и приведите сформированный html и сразу сниппетом с вашим js. Если утверждаете что с пхп все в порядке, то зачем вообще 70% вопроса на него потратили не ясно.

Comment: Да, пожалуй php тут ни к чему, но вопрос остается актуальным

Comment: @NIKKIT Так и просьба остается актуальной, оформите html и js в воспроизводимый сниппет. Кстати, не так давно [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1393059/443096) на подобный вопрос.

Comment: запустил ваш текст, вроде сортирует.

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov может быть все дело в том что таблица выводится средствами php? Пожалуй все же верну php код. Подключаю ее в код с помощью include

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov Действительно, если код в разметке html, все работает. Как только загружаю средством php, отказывается сортировать

Comment: @NIKKIT Так сравните html на выходе php-скрипта и тот, что работает.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey По моему он идентичен тому что написал на html, если увидите несоответствие, дайте обратную связь пожалуйста

Comment: @NIKKIT смотрите внимательней, у вас на каждый tr генерируется tbody, а в готовом варианте все в одном

Comment: @ValentinDrozdov Да, вы правы, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все как всегда проще, тег tbody был внутри цикла и повторялся раз за разом.